# Can push notifications be sent from scratch orgs?

Tags: salesforcedx, mobile, mobilepush

We have connected app that's part of our managed package, and has always been defined in the Packaging Org itself. Recently I've been looking at adding push notifications to our application, so I configured the required settings in the packaging org and ran some tests from the dev console there to verify they're actually working, and they are.

Now I need to actually do the code modifications to our app to add the support for creating them. We use DX, so use scratch orgs for development and then push the converted source to the packaging org when it's time for release.

Where I'm stuck is trying to test the push notifications in a scratch org. I retrieved the connected app metadata from the packaging org using `sfdx force:source:retrieve`, and pulled out the consumer key after I found I couldn't push it to the scratch org with it in (thanks to Mr. Ballinger for that one).

Now the issue I've got is that I get this error when trying to send a notification via execute anonymous in the dev console:

> System.NoAccessException: Invalid connected application: [AppName] with Namespace: [NS]

I've modified the admin profile to have access to the connected app but to no avail, and can't think of anything else to try. Incidentally the push notification settings are missing from the connected app, but if I try and add the certificate I get a super helpful error at the top of the page that reads:

> A general data error occurred with your entries

Am I doing something completely wrong here or is it just likely that his scenario's never been tested with scratch orgs?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever got this working @matt?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think you could maybe do it via a different connected app in a different managed package that you install in the scratch orgs, but then you'd need a different mobile app build too!